# elasticsearch/haystack not persisting across server restarts

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch, django-haystack

I have a simple project indexing some Django models in to ElasticSearch via Haystack. If I restart the ElasticSearch server, I get no results out of Haystack unless I update the index.

I think that the system should be persisting the indexed models across ES restarts, but can't find what im potentially doing wrong. Everything else works fine otherwise.

My query is very simple: `SearchQuerySet().order_by('-published').all()`, again it returns no results when ES first starts until I re-index/update-index.

Any ideas?

Comment: What version of ES are you using and how are you restarting ES

Comment: 1.0.0 restarted via systemctl

Comment: There's a couple things you can try, install head plugin (wherever your install is, sudo elasticsearch/bin/plugin --install mobz/elasticsearch-head) and just see what is going on. 2. Take a look at your data dir, usually in `/var/lib/elasticsearch/` see if it's spawning multiple nodes (cd down to the nodes directory, in general you should have only one directory called 0), sometimes if you restart ES too fast, it will spawn a new node, looking like you lost your data. 3. Did you tinker with "store"?

Answer (score 1):

In case you didn't index a lot of data, elasticsearch possibly didn't write the data onto disk. Try to '_flush' the data before restarting.

In the following document '_flush' is nicely described: 
    http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.x/indices-flush.html